# wget logfile, how to set the unit to be seconds, and kilobytes

Tags: c, wget

The last three lines in the wget log file, with -nv option, are

```
 FINISHED --2015-02-11 21:52:07--
 Total wall clock time: 4.8s
 Downloaded: 6 files, 316K in 1.7s (182 KB/s)
```

I want to read these lines with c, So I want the 316K to be always in K, (I don't want to have 2.3M etc) Also I want the time to be always in sec (Not in minute, hours etc).

PS
in the main.c (in the wget source)

```
             logprintf (LOG_NOTQUIET,
              _("FINISHED --%s--\nTotal wall clock time: %s\n"
               "Downloaded: %d files, %s in %s (%s)\n"),
             datetime_str (time (NULL)),
             wall_time,
             numurls,
             human_readable (total_downloaded_bytes, 10, 1),
             download_time,
             retr_rate (total_downloaded_bytes,      total_download_time));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist in modifying `wget`, change the above to

```
  logprintf (LOG_NOTQUIET,
             _("FINISHED --%s--\nTotal wall clock time: %s\n"
               "Downloaded: %d files, %ldK in %lds (%s)\n"),
             datetime_str (time (NULL)),
             wall_time,
             numurls,
             (long)(total_downloaded_bytes/1024),
             (long)total_download_time,
             retr_rate (total_downloaded_bytes, total_download_time));
```

- but you should reconsider handling the several units in your C program.